# display_network in Extreme Learning Machines

Tags: matlab

I am new in Matlab, learning ELM.Now facing a problem

when i follow [Code using MNIST Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Using_the_MNIST_Dataset)

After  `display_network(images(1:100));`
Get error  `Undefined function 'display_network' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

This is my problem now, Thanks if you have any other information about ELM
 please share
This is my first Question,anything wrong, please tell me :)

Comment: I assume you've downloaded and installed their code following any provided directions (including the comments in the example you're running). Have added it to your `path` or changed your directory to the root of that code? Type `which display_network` in your Command Window.

Comment: i got `'display_network' not found.` thanks

Comment: Then you haven't followed the instructions on the page or `display_network` is not on your path (or the same directory as the MNIST files). Have you downloaded the [autoencoder module](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/MATLAB_Modules) as is mentioned?

Comment: You have to download the function display_network from autoencoder toolbox. here you go:   https://github.com/dgboy2000/sparseAutoencoder/blob/master/display_network.m